# Registry Key: Deletion Error

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, administration

While "playing" with the private software install/uninstall my system ended up in bad state.
There is a key that's causing my application installation to fail and I can not delete it by any means:

> Cannot delete ........key: Error while deleting this key" error,
>   nothing is logged in EventViewer

I've Administrator privilege and tried everything that search engine offers:

1. Tried to Change Permissions
2. Tried to Change Owner
3. Tried to use RegDelNul

Any advanced ideas how to get rid of this Registry Key?

Thanks.

Comment: @Azho KG, have you tried opening `regedit` in Adminstrative Mode?

Comment: What is the registry key and on what Windows version does this happen? Perhaps the key is being used by a running process. Did you try using safe mode to remove it?

Comment: @Devendra I've opened(run) regedit as an Administrator.

Comment: @Azho KG, as suggested by @Cosmin Pirvu, try booting into the safe mode and then deleting the entries.

Comment: @Cosmin The key was created by my private software, it's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\D2026AE5B383EA745954B5366F9F491D\BF27BE2998B4D5E45BA3BB8EC0FF2C0C 

How to find whether the key is being used by a software (Actually it shouldn't be, but OS may mistakenly thinking that it's in use).

Comment: I'm using VM and was not able to login in safe mode. It's not responding to F8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to re-image the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem (although this was with a key from a driver from a large software company).

I tried the same change owner, reboot, etc.  After twiddling with regedit I found the following process to work:

1. Find parent key in `regedit`
2. Right mouse, Permissions, Advanced, Owner Tab
3. Check Replace owner on subcontainers
4. Select myself as owner
5. Click OK
6. On Permissions dialog, Click Add ...
7. Type user name
8. Click OK
9. Click Full Control
10. Click OK

Repeat steps 1-10 for sub-key.  I had to refresh (F5) and recursively repeat for about 20 keys.

---

After having to do this again.  I found that if I repeatedly perform steps 1-10 on the parent key (about 4 times each) I eventually get to a point where all the properties have been propagated.  This is faster than doing it recursively.